# Linux distro for netbook

Tags: linux-distribution

I'm looking into the best Linux distribution for a netbook.

It's an upgraded Acer Aspire One D270 (Intel Atom N2600 1.6GHz, 3GB RAM, 750GB HD), which will be used mainly for daily tasks:

- web browsing,
- text editing,
- image editing, and
- a Skype call now and then.

I tried installing Linux Mint 18.1 XFCE, everything works fine but the general response seems a bit slow in general. Mint was my first choice just because I use it in my other machines already, but maybe someone could recommend me another distro that would suit the netbook better?

I've heard some of the lightweight versions of Ubuntu 16.04 could be good, but since Mint is based on Ubuntu I wonder if there would be much of a change at all.

Comment: Thanks @danijelc for pointing that out. Since most of the replies to that question talk about distros that are now outdated I thought opening a new thread would be better, but I can close it again if it's considered a duplicate...

Comment: @arroba: If you think it’s a duplicate, it should be closed as such (not deleted). But is it really a duplicate? Maybe you have other requirements than the OP of the linked question? If that’s the case, you could [edit] your question to state these requirements (and possibly link to the other question in case the difference is not obvious)

Comment: @arroba every question would be outdated with logic of distro updates. But since in your case it looks like you need a basic system to just work, most of replies there meet the criteria with simply installing a newer version of the distro.